# Miners - HTTP JSON-RPC or JSON-RPC?

Tags: json-rpc, protocol, mining-software, getwork, http

Does the main miner software used currently use HTTP JSON-RPC, or JSON-RPC? That is, do they use HTTP calls to obtain getwork, or TCP/IP?

Comment: They use RPC over JSON over HTTP over TCP/IP. These aren't alternatives, each of these protocols does a different thing and exists at a different layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The miner uses JSON-RPC 1.0, for which only the HTTP transport was defined.